# Magento Image Thumbnail not showing in cart page

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

when i click to add to cart button the thumbnail image is not showing on the cart page

i have attached a screen shot i don't know from where it is coming i am new to magneto. image is coming everywhere but it is showing only on the cart page . We have not done any changes in the code neither we did something on the `cart.phtml file`

[image]

Comment: is your product's image saved as thumbnail?

Comment: check the console in the browser for the issues

Comment: you can enable the template path hints to see from where the code is called